# In MongoDB How to use equivalent of $out Operator in find() to copy data into another collection?

Tags: mongodb, syntax-error, mongodb-query

I want to copy in MongoDB result of a query into another collection using find() instead of aggregate()
My query is as below:

```
db.fd2kfullsample.find({A_DELAY: {$lt: 0}, D_DELAY: {$lt: 0}})
```

$out is used with an aggregate() function and not find I tried the following which did not work:

```
db.fd2kfullsample.find({ $or: [ { A_DELAY: {$lt: 0}} ,{ D_DELAY: {$lt: 
0} } , {$out: "test2"}] })

Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "unknown top level operator: $out",
    "code" : 2,
    "codeName" : "BadValue"
}
```

Do you know how to use find() function and write the output of this query to a collection?

or

Do you know how to form an aggregate query which meets the same result with $out operator?

A Million Thanks in advance for your Answers!

Comment: use an aggregation query with a [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `$match` operation of the aggregation framework.

```
db.fd2kfullsample.aggregate({ $match: { $or: [ { A_DELAY: { $lt: 0 } },{  D_DELAY: { $lt: 0 } }] } }, { $out: "test2" })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you deliberately want to use find() and still wants to create the new table based on output following snippet is the help (Tested with mongodb v2.2)

```
db.fullset.find({A_DELAY: {$lt: 0}, D_DELAY: {$lt: 0}}).forEach(function(doc){
   db.subset.insert(doc);
});
```

On-wards mondodb 2.6, $out operator along with aggregate() is the recommended approch.